# Opamp-bjt circuit question

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt

I am solving the operating point of this circuit to find \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$I_{C}\$, assuming ideal opamp and BJT.

Due to the opamp the node \$B\$ is a virtual ground so \$V_{OUT}\$ is from the voltage divider \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ and with \$V_{DD} = 10V\$, \$V_{OUT} \approx 9.95V\$.
Now how can I get the \$I_{C}\$, given \$\beta_F = 200\$? Is the BJT in saturation mode?

I have also tried simulating the circuit in LTSpice but I get strange results: using real component (LT1001 and 2N2222) \$V_{OUT}\approx -9.95V\$, with ideal components \$V_{OUT}\approx -0.002V\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Ky1L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: LT1001 doesn't have rail-to-rail outputs. It can't drive the output close enough to -VDD to keep Q1 at a reasonable operating point.

Comment: So should I consider the simulation with ideal component correct? (and my analysis wrong?)

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis --- Node B is kept at ground by having 0 V at Vout. Which simulation you should look at depends whether you intend to build the circuit with real components or ideal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's intended to sit with output at 0V (or slightly off 0V depending on the bias current and offset voltage of the amplifier), meaning Ic = Vdd/1K since the non-inverting input is at virtual ground (and since R1/R4 are symmetric about ground they (ideally) have no effect). The beta does not enter into the calculation.

It won't work using the LT1001, for the reason @ThePhoton indicates (the output can't swing down to -Vdd + 0.6V or so) but also the additional gain from the transistor means that this circuit, when made with realistic parts, is actually an oscillator which will not yield a stable DC output value.

---

Edit:

Here is an LTspice simulation that illustrates the above using the op-amp you tried. I have added a -15V supply for the op-amp to deal with the first problem and made the transistor into an integrator via  R6/C1 to deal with the stability issue.

[image]

Comment: Of course I have only forgot that B is a _virtual_ ground and not an actual one, so with the addition that R1 and R4 are symmetrical no current flows through R3 and Vout is 0V. Thank you both for the tip. (This is an exercise presented as an amplifier.)